# How to extract first paragraph using Regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract the below first paragraph.

```
corpus = "CHRISTINE MOORMAN and REBECCA J. SLOTEGRAAF*

 Current interdisciplinary research suggests that organizational capabil-
 ities have a direct, unconditional impact on firm performance. The authors
 extend this literature by developing a framework that proposes a contin-
 gency approach to the value of organizational capabilities. This frame-
 work highlights the effect of information in the external environment in
 stimulating firms to deploy their technology and marketing capabilities to
 influence the level and speed of relevant product development activities.
 

 The Contingency Value of Complementary Capabilities in Product Development."
```

I was able to select the uppercase letters from the corpus as starting point but unable to set the end point.

my regex pattern to search uppercase is :

```
r'+[A-Z]\W\s'
```

The above text was taken from PDF file so it would be really appreciated if i can find a general pattern to fetch similar text from other files.

Please find the sample PDF image : https://ibb.co/FW9V0nk

```
preferred_output = ['Current interdisciplinary research suggests that organizational capabil-ities have a direct, unconditional impact on firm performance. The authors extend this literature by developing a framework that proposes a contin-gency approach to the value of organizational capabilities. This frame-work highlights the effect of information in the external environment in stimulating firms to deploy their technology and marketing capabilities to
influence the level and speed of relevant product development activities.']
```

Comment: From where in the text are you interested and till what point?

Comment: Apologize, added my preferred output in the question.

Comment: I think it can be done pretier but maybe something like `text = re.search(r'(?<=\n\n).*(?=\n\n)', corpus, re.DOTALL)`

Comment: is there a way i can get the text i need as a list ?

Comment: Through `re.findall` you mean?

Comment: "...if i can find a general pattern to fetch similar text from other files." is too general. I suggest you break your second paragraph into multiple paragraphs and then ask specific questions, and for each show the desired result. For example, you said "I was able to select the uppercase letters" without saying what you want to extract. For example, if you said, "I want to select all text beginning with a double quote followed by a capital letter to the end of the paragraph" it would be `"CHRISTINE MOORMAN and REBECCA J. SLOTEGRAAF*`. Do the same for other questions you ask about the text.

Answer (score 0):

here is your general Regex(this is for your current string **style**, And it's assumed that the other strings have the same style. Otherwise, you can change the pattern a bit:

```
import regex as re
x = [re.search(r'\n\n((.*\n)*?\n)', corpus).group(1).replace('\n', '')]
print(x)
```

- `\n\n` find the first paragraph
- `(.*\n)` tests for a string starting a new line (first line of paragraph).
- `*?\n` match    the string till next empty line.(repeat previous regex till where the paragraph ends)
- `()` around that makes sure all    lines come in one capture group.

OUTPUT:

```
[' Current interdisciplinary research suggests that organizational capabil- ities have a direct, unconditional impact on firm performance. The authors extend this literature by developing a framework that proposes a contin- gency approach to the value of organizational capabilities. This frame- work highlights the effect of information in the external environment in stimulating firms to deploy their technology and marketing capabilities to influence the level and speed of relevant product development activities. ']
```